# Django NoReverseMatch problems with get_absolute_url

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I know this probably the single most common Django problem there is, but I can't for the life of me figure this one out. I'll make it quick.

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns += [
    path('certs/', views.certs, name='certs'),
    path('certs/<int:id>/', views.view_cert, name='view_cert'),
]
```

-

```
# views.py
@login_required
def certs(request):
    certs = Certification.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'certs.html', {'certs': certs})


def view_cert(request, id):
    cert = Certification.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'view_cert.html', {'cert': cert})
```

-

```
# certs.html
{% if certs %}
    <ul class="list-group">
    {% for cert in certs %}
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ cert.name }}</li>
        <!--<a href="{% url cert.get_absolute_url %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ cert.name }}</a>-->
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

-

```
# models.py
class Certification(models.Model):
...
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('crypto:view_cert', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

The code works absolutely fine when i load /certs/1 for example. However when I try to load /certs (which should list a users certs), I get a NoReverseMatch.

```
Reverse for '/certs/1/' not found. '/certs/1/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

What's even more confusing is that I can load it absolutely fine from shell:

```
>>> from django.urls import reverse
>>> reverse('crypto:view_cert', kwargs={'id': 1})
'/certs/1/'
>>>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since result of `get_absolute_url` is url string you dont need `{% url %}` in template to use it. Just replace it with:

```
<a href="{{ cert.get_absolute_url }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ cert.name }}</a>
```

Comment: Oh the joys of learning new environments. Two days of stress over that. Thank you times a million!